# Not see image after shared article to Facebook with FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject

Tags: objective-c, fbsdk

I try to shared image to Facebook and I need that the app name was be in the shared post in Facebook

this is the code :

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
UIImage *image1 = [GeneralMethods imageConvertToSizeWithImage:postImageView.image scaledToWidth:300];
photo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"VImage.png"];
photo.userGenerated = YES;

NSDictionary *properties = @{
                             @"og:type": @"article",
                             @"og:title": @"new item",
                             @"og:description": @"bla bla",
//                                 @"og:image": @[photo],
                             };
FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];



//    [object setPhoto:photo forKey:@"og:image"];

// Create an action
FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
action.actionType = @"news.publishes";


[action setObject:object forKey:@"article"];


// Add the photo to the action. Actions
// can take an array of images.
[action setArray:@[photo] forKey:@"image"];

// Create the content
FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
content.action = action;
content.previewPropertyName = @"article";

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:ParetDelaget withContent:content  delegate:self];
```

this is Facebook preview page with the image i add:

[image]

this is the post in my Facebook wall without image :

[image]

whats I do wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncomment this line:

```
//                                 @"og:image": @[photo],
```

And comment this one:

```
[action setArray:@[photo] forKey:@"image"];
```

Like this you will have both image, title and description showing.

A little remark: the photo object must be a string URL

In my case, here is the resulting code:

```
// Create an object  
NSDictionary *properties = @{
                             @"og:type": @"article",
                             @"og:url": @"https://the_link_you_want.com",
                             @"og:title": @"your title",
                             @"og:description": @"your description",
                             @"og:image": @"http://url_to_your_image"
                             };

FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject  objectWithProperties:properties];

// Create an action
FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
action.actionType = @"news.publishes";

[action setObject:object forKey:@"article"];

// Create the content
FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
content.action = action;
content.previewPropertyName = @"article";


FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
shareDialog.fromViewController = self;
shareDialog.shareContent = content;
[shareDialog show];

if (![shareDialog canShow]) {
    // update the app UI accordingly
}
NSError *error;
if (![shareDialog validateWithError:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"FB Error: %@", error);
}
```

Hope that helps